# Store persistent data on Services ( Angular 2 )

Tags: angular, typescript

First of all i would like to share the next info:
I have two services, one that gets the http request and another that store data. I tried a lot of ways but i can't get it. I wanna store data on the second service to get the data from differents components and dont DRY (on every component).

**The specific problem:** I get the http request from the API, then i want to store the json response (store on array or object) to get persistent data and get the info on every component. I will share what i tried, but it didnt work on the second service (artist.service.ts).

```
// spotify.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {


  urlSpotify: string = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/';
  token: string = 'BQDejsMxhS-8621YfIhK_X6uxZcFY4LIBTNNxVIDAPimiBBU5t7lQlQCUboZkt5JBypYq-IH4dv9bhxQgaU';


  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('SpotyApp Ready');
   }

   private getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
     let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'authorization': `Bearer ${ this.token }`
      });

     return headers;
   } 



getArtista( id: string ) {
       let url = `${ this.urlSpotify }artists/${ id }`;

      let headers = this.getHeaders();

      return this.http.get(url, { headers});
   }

   // Methods
```

---

```
// artist.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SpotifyService } from './spotify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class ArtistService {

artist: any = {};

constructor(private _spotify: SpotifyService, public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

 // It doesnt work....
 getArtista(id): Observable<any> {
    if (this.artist) {
        return Observable.of(this.artist);
    }
    return this._spotify.getArtista(id).do(artist => {
        console.log(artist, 'Artista');
        this.artist = artist;
    });
 }


  // It doesnt work...It works only on EVERY component.

getArtista(): void{
this.route.params.map(params => params['id'])
  .subscribe(id => {
    this._spotify.getArtista(id)
      .subscribe(artist => {
        console.log(artist, 'Artista');
            this.artist = artist;
      });
```

---

```
// artist.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArtistService } from '../../services/artist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist',
  templateUrl: './artist.component.html'
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

  artist: any = {};


  constructor(public _artist: ArtistService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artist = this._artist.getArtista();
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work? You enter a new page, a new API call is made and you get a result. Is your understanding that `this.artist` should contain information when you make second, third and more future function calls to the `ArtistService`?

Comment: You have declarated artist as: artist: any **= {}**; and if (artist){ return Observable.of(this.artis). You MUST declare artist simply as artist:any or artist:any=null

Comment: @Eliseo is right. Your condition `if(this.artist)` will always return `true`.

Comment: The real problem is that i always get "undefined". So i want to know what im doing wrong.. I would like to get an observable to subscribe on the current component and get the artist, the album, etc...@DanielB Sorry , i dont get it when you say second, third, etc...So if i just make one function call, i wont get any data ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to cache artists on the service to avoid repeated calls, but the cache should also have a map based on the `id` of the artist. Also a caching mechanism is never as easy as it seems when you think of cache getting dirty with other operations. It is highly recommended not to cache it if the network calls are not that expensive. Traditionally there is a trend towards minimising network calls, but I personally doesn't think some KBs will matter to the User.

Also, the use of `ActivatedRoute` is better suited in the corresponding component and keep the service limited to its purpose.

Also **persistence** makes no sense here. Its storing in volatile variables. Persistence should at least refer to local storage.

```
// artist.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SpotifyService } from './spotify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class ArtistService {
artistsSources = {};
artists = {};
constructor(private _spotify: SpotifyService) {}

 getArtista(id): Observable<any> {
    if(this.artists[id]) {
        return this.artists[id];
    } else {
        this.artistsSources[id] = new BehaviorSubject(null);
        this.artists[id] = this.artistsSources[id].asObservable().filter(Boolean);

        this._spotify.getArtista(id).do(artist => this.artistsSources[id].next(artist));
    }
    return this.artists[id];
 }
}
```

---

```
// artist.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArtistService } from '../../services/artist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist',
  templateUrl: './artist.component.html'
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

  artist: Observable<any>;


  constructor(public _artist: ArtistService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.artist = this.route.params.map(params => params['id'])
        .switchMap(id =>  this._artist.getArtista(id))
        // you can optionally subscribe here and set this.artist as normal object
        // this example uses async pipe in template instead
        // if you subscribe, make sure you unsusbscribe in onDestry
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

---

```
//artist.component.html

{{(artist | async)?.name}}
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer but i want persisent data on a service just to not make repetition. I have artist component, album component, another component. With a service i store the data and a want to subscribe ( something like that ) on every component to get the current album,tracks, artist, etc...